# Edit rails app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, edit, osx-mountain-lion, production-environment

I'm hoping you can help.. I have inherited a small site in rails that I have been tasked to edit. I have a good understanding of PHP, but am a total newbie to rails.

I need to make a very simple edit to a file, which I have done, but it is not showing up on the site when I save. The file is located in the config directory. I have restarted the machine it is being served from (Mac OS 10.8), I have searched online for a number of answers including disabling caches, changing config.cache_classes to false and config.consider_all_requests_local to true, but nothing seems to work. The site is using unicorn as the server.

What am I missing? I realise this is probably a terrible way to work with rails, and I've promised myself I will learn it, but for now I just need to know how to make live changes as I  am used to FTPing changes with html, php etc.

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 2):

If you have restarted the machine it is being served from and the changes still don't show up, then you were editing the wrong file alltogether.  Maybe it's really served from another folder on this machine?  Or from another machine?

Comment: Hi thanks. The file I am editing is in the config folder, in a subfolder called initializers. The file is simple, just three separate if statements to deal with scheduling certain actions. I only changed the interval at which these actions were scheduled. It's definitely on this machine as I copied it from our "production" machine to this one to see if I could configure it to run, so it's in production on a development machine if that makes sense? :)

Comment: It's called purge_old_pickups.rb - presumably a custom file for this app.

Answer (score 0):

probably just need to run  touch tmp/restart.txt from the app root dir if you have ssh access

PROJECTDIR/tmp/restart.txt

you can open tmp/restart.txt on your FTP server via any text editor and press Ctrl+S (save it), so file will be touched and server will be restarted

or if you have ssh access run

touch tmp/restart.txt from your rails app root

---

---EDIT---

Sorry didn't see the part where you said you had restarted the machine. More likely an issue with assets pipeline.

Try deleting public/assets

and then running

bundle exec rake assets:precompile

I think there is a command to clear and recompile but I can't remember it

Also if these answers don't help it might be helpful to know what you have actually edited and how. Is it css? Markup? A controller?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. I deleted public/assets and ran the precompile, then I restarted the machine, still not updated. The file I am editing is in the config folder, in a subfolder called initializers. The file is simple, just three separate if statements to deal with scheduling certain actions. I only changed the interval at which these actions were scheduled.

Comment: What is the name of the file in initializers sub dir. There are some ruby scripts which trigger cronjobs for example which will need console commands to be run

Comment: It's called purge_old_pickups.rb - presumably a custom file for this app.

Comment: Post the code of this file and I'm sure people will be able to help.

Comment: I'm changing a single line. `if (Time.now - p.created_at)/60 > 5 && p.status == "Open"` to `if (Time.now - p.created_at)/60 > 2 && p.status == "Open"` Just changing the interval from **5** to **2**. The line is in the file purge_old_pickups.rb file in config/initializers. It is a small file of 30 lines that schedules the refresh rate of the page, and how long it stores information in a SQLite db. The code works as expected, before I make my change, but afterwards it does not change to 2 minutes.

Comment: without seeing the line of code that is run when this logic is true it's still hard to give a difinitive answer however it still seems like running the command "touch tmp/restart.txt" from project dir would do the trick since initializers are always reloaded on a restart

Comment: Hi Jon, this is the code in full.

`require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.every("1m") do

  @needs_delivery = []

  Pickup.all.each do |p|
    if (Time.now - p.created_at)/60 > 1 && p.status == "Open"
      @needs_delivery << p
    end
  end

  if @needs_delivery.count == 1
    system("say There is #{@needs_delivery.count} item that needs to be delivered. &")
  elsif @needs_delivery.count > 1
    system("say There are #{@needs_delivery.count} items that need to be delivered. &")
  end
end`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20701/discussion-between-rory-dale-and-jon-day)

Answer (score 0):

It is common to deploy Rails applications using software called Capistrano.  If you find files `app/Capfile` and `app/config/deploy.rb` then your app is using it.  The typical workflow with Capistrano is

- get a local copy of your application from a source control repository (e.g. using `git clone` from GitHub)
- edit files locally (and test, but you may not be there)
- commit and push to source control
- run `cap deploy` to do all of the things that may be needed, e.g. recompiling asssets

What capistrano does (in the most basic usage) is:

- create a subdirectory in `your-app-name/releases/<date-filename>/`
- get the latest code from the source control repository into that directory (e.g. `git pull`)
- replace a symbolic link in `your-app-name/current` with one to the new directory
- restart the server (if using Phusion Passenger, `touch your-app-name/current/tmp/restart.txt` does the trick, otherwise, you might need to restart the web server

As noted in another answer, changes to "assets" (CSS, JS, images) will need to be recompiled.  I think running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` from the `<your-app-name>` subdirectory is all that is needed, but if things get messed up, run `bundle exec rake assets:clean` first.

In some cases, capistrano and source control are set up to require that deployments use the local credentials of the user doing the deploy -- this is supported by `ssh-agent` and the `ssh-add` commands.  You would need these if your source control system does not allow access from the server directly (you'll see a line `ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true` in your `app/config/deploy.rb` if this is how it's set up).

Of course there can be many other dependencies that need to be managed depending on your environment.  If you have even a remotely advanced environment, you should do the work of figuring out how to deploy the right way, probably with capistrano.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your help. Capistrano is not currently configured. I installed it, but I'm still struggling. I got a bit lost after creating a GitHub account, installing Git, and selecting a repository... I don't have any of that yet, just a local copy of the app that is run on a local network. I don't know if I should create a repository because I didn't write the app. I'm not completely clear on how GitHub works yet. :(

Comment: Oh my ... well forget capistrano and github!  Sorry, I don't really have much more than has already been said.

Comment: I need to get studying, and I will! Thanks for you help. I'm a little shocked it's so hard to make such a simple change to what is essentially just a small website. What would have taken me seconds in PHP has taken hours so far. Thank you again for your time, this resource is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do in the end, and I realise this is not the way you are meant to work with Rails..

I backed up the app directory, re-imaged the dev machine I was using to test it. Performed a clean installation of Ruby on Rails as per http://rubyonrails.org/download. I created a new empty app with the same name, then copied the contents of the app I was working with to the new app skeleton choosing not to overwrite any existing files. Then I installed Passenger and ran it as a standalone. This got my app up and running again, and now when I made any changes to the file in config/initializers they were reflected when I restarted passenger. So I'm good to go.

Now I need to learn how to really do it.. Thanks all.